# How do I fix these HTML validation errors?

Tags: html, reactjs, validation

I'm trying to fix some html validation errors, but I'm not sure how considering I'm using React and the JSX is rendering HTML to the browser. I don't have direct access to the html that's being rendered.

[image]

[image]

[image]

As you can see, I'm not even using a 'link' element. I'm not quite sure how to approach this. I bet this is a simple thing to fix, but I'm lost and google doesn't help, as far as I've looked. Any ideas?

Comment: Your app probably has some kind of `index.html` file somewhere in which the React bundle is loaded. This is where you'll usually find the `head` and `body` of the document.

Comment: I see two. One in the build folder and one in the public folder

Comment: But both have the <!doctype html>

Comment: We're lacking too much information to really help you. Please include a [mcve] or enough information about your project's setup. Is it a create-react-app project? Next? etc

Comment: it's a create-react-app project. https://github.com/tphelps93/spaced-repetition/blob/master/src/routes/LearningRoute/LearningRoute.js This is the component that I'm working on.

Comment: What tool are you using to validate the HTML of the page?

Comment: https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea

Comment: If I [validate the deployed client app](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Fspaced-rep-client.tphelps93.vercel.app%2Fregister) (found on the github link), it validates the right HTML and finds no errors.

Comment: My evaluator told me to use these steps 

1. Visit your page and open up the Elements tab of your Chrome Developer Tools.
2. Right click the <html> element and select Copy > Copy outerHTML.
3. Paste the results into https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input.

That html that I copy is what is giving me the errors

Comment: Obviously, if you manually copy the `<html ...>` tag, leaving out the `doctype` just above, the validator is going to complain about it! Your evaluator probably asks you to do this because React renders HTML after the page has loaded and validating by URL (like I did) doesn't take into account the resulting HTML from React, just the initial HTML that's on the page.

Comment: oh great then what am I supposed to do? lol I guess I'll have to just try to correct him.

Comment: Manually adding `<!DOCTYPE html>` before pasting the rest of the document would fix that error.

Comment: It looks like there already is a <!DOCTYPE html> before it.

Comment: Not in the textarea it seems, as it says in the screenshot above.